# How do I set cookies from parsed xml data?

Tags: php, xml, cookies

I'm trying to set values in a simple xml file into separate cookies. I can successfully acquire the xml file from an online database, place it into a variable and grab a value from it. The problem happens when I try to make a cookie from that variable. I tested the variable by printing it out and the value is there.

I'm using php 5.4.10 and the code is on a straight php page with no html.

I'd really appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

A very simple example of the code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($geo);
$cylon = $xml->places->Array->city;
setcookie("user_city", $cylon, time()+3600, '/', 'mysite.com');
```

An example of the xml file is:

```
<Response>
<places>
<Array pos="0">
<city>~New York</city>
<country>United States</country>
<position>
<lat>54.11228774</lat>
<lon>-152.76592584</lon>
</position>
<state>NY</state>
<street>Broadway</street>
<zip>10001</zip>
</Array>
</places>
<status>
<duration>44</duration>
<procedure>geo.location.search.2</procedure>
<success>true</success>
</status>
</Response>
```

Comment: what's the issue? the cookie won't contain the value of `~New York` or it isn't being set at all?

Comment: The cookie isn't being set.

Comment: it might be from the last two parameters; try this instead: `setcookie("user_city", $cylon, time()+3600);`

Comment: josh, that did it, I don't know why it would matter but removing this parameters worked. Thanks!

Comment: it's probably because the last two parameters define a very strict subset of where the cookie can be accessed from (in that example, '/' meant only in the root directory files, and 'mysite.com' meant only mysite.com can retrieve that cookie. See: http://us1.php.net/setcookie